# JOINing 3 tables with MAX function

Tags: mysql, vb.net, join, max, multiple-tables

I have an issue with a complex query (at least for me); I have done this with for loops but I want to know if there is a better solution.

I have 3 tables.

Table: pnmaster

1. PN (Primary Key)
2. Description
3. Type

Table: buys

1. PN (NOT primary)
2. Quantity
3. Date

Table: consume

1. PN (NOT primary)
2. Quantity
3. Date

I want to perform a query that selects from pnmaster the PN with Type="X" and joins the corresponding latest buy made and the latest consume made and its Quantitys for each PN. I have tried the following piece of code and works fine with 1 Join, but with 2 it hangs for at least 10 minutes.

```
SELECT pnmaster.PN,pnmaster.Description,buy.Quantity,consume.Quantity,
       MAX(consume.Date),MAX(buy.Date) FROM pnmaster 
       INNER JOIN consume ON pnmaster.PN=consume.PN 
       INNER JOIN buy ON pnmaster.PN=buy.PN WHERE(pnmaster.Type='X') 
       GROUP BY PN;
```

Example, starting with pnmaster:

```
PN Desc
A  Seal
B  Screw
C  Hammer
```

buys:

```
PN Qty Date
A   2   01/01/2013
A   3   01/02/2014
B   1   01/07/2011
C   7   01/05/2014
C   4   01/03/2012
C   3   01/02/2013
```

consumes:

```
PN Qty Date
A   4   01/01/2010
A   7   01/02/2012
B   3   01/07/2010
C   1   01/05/2013
C   9   01/03/2011
C   3   01/02/2015
```

Expected Result:

```
PN Desc  LastBuy LastConsume LastBuyDate LastConsumeDate
A  Seal    3         7        01/02/2014   01/02/2012
B  Screw   1         3        01/07/2011   01/07/2010
C  Hammer  3         3        01/02/2013   01/02/2015
```

Comment: EDIT:
Forgot to mention, if there is no last consume or last buy the PN with description must remain in the query, resulting BuyQty = 0 and Consume Qty=0, LastBuyDate and LastConsume Date= "N/A". 
Thanks for your response Adam i will try your query tomorrow as soon as i arrive at my job.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better query for this...but you could use:

```
SELECT
    m.PN
    ,m.Description
    ,(
    SELECT Quantity FROM buys WHERE Date = (
        SELECT MAX(Date) FROM buys WHERE PN = m.PN
        )
    ) AS LastBuyQty
    ,(
    SELECT MAX(Date) FROM buys WHERE PN = m.PN
    ) AS LastBuyDate
    ,(
    SELECT Quantity FROM consumes WHERE Date = (
        SELECT MAX(Date) FROM consumes WHERE PN = m.PN
        )
    ) AS LastConsumeQty
    ,(
    SELECT MAX(Date) FROM consumes WHERE PN = m.PN
    ) AS LastConsumeDate
FROM pnmaster AS m
WHERE m.PN = 'A';
```